# Keyboard overlaps text boxes

Tags: keyboard, lineageos, text-input

I've been having this strange issue for a while where my keyboard overlaps in app text boxes. It happens with every kind of text box that sits on top of the keyboard. It seems like it aligns with the bottom of the selected text rather than the box. It's really annoying to type this way. Especially when trying to edit something higher up in the text. I then have to close the keyboard in order to be able to go back to the end and put my cursor there.

I attached a screen shot of the issue. It's showing SwiftKey but it also happens with the default keyboard.

I'm running lineage os 17.1.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the ROM in question is not a stable release. Custom ROM bugs are best to be addressed by their developers. Our policy is to close such questions. See https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2077/96277

Comment: it would be good if your report this as a bug to LOS developers. They can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is not a common issue as I have found nobody else having it. I found that the issue is only present in the full screen mode (i.e: when te status bar is hidden). Cant really wrap my head around why that would happen but at least it's a fix for now.